# Truncate table with constraints

Tags: t-sql

Rather than having to go to each child table and completely dropping constraints related to the table that you wanna do a truncate on, is there a quick way to just disable any conflicting constraints quickly and easily to allow me to truncate and get out without having to do a drop/add which is combursome?

Answer (score -1):

```
-- Disable all constraints including dependencies:
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableNamesDependencies NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

-- Truncate tables:
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TableName;
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TableNamesDependencies ;

-- Enable all constraints:
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableNamesDependencies NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```